# Issue while creating subfolder in Azure cloud

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am using the Azure Api provided by Microsoft for cloud storage...I am facing an unusual bug while creating the sub folder.
i.e when I create a subfolder within any container it is created easily within seconds. But when I try to create a subfolder again with different name it takes more time as compared to the previous one.

Again I try it is created easily. It means the sub folder no. 1 , 3 ,5 ,7 and so on are created easily and the even no. such as 2, 4 etc sub folders are created with delay.
i.e "Alternate sub folder creation is taking too much time"

Please let me know if there is any solution for this bug...

Comment: Are you seeing any throttling exceptions (possibly hidden within the SDK itself, if you are using that)?

Comment: subfolders? do you have some repro code to show?

Comment: Here is the sample code which is working fine for creating the so called subfolders in Azure..but it works inconsistently........                            NameValueCollection containerMetadata = new NameValueCollection();
 Blobcontainer.CreateFolderBlob(newBlobProperties("subfolder/dummy.png"), null);

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating these in blob storage? Folders, strictly speaking don't exist. They are simply a '/' character (or whatever delimiter you specify) are that imbedded in the file names. So you save a file using a path with out implicitly creating the path.

In the documentation, they even refer to these as "vitual folders" because they don't actual exist.

Comment: yes i am following the same approach....subfolder/dummy.png 

the first subfolder is created at ease whereas the second time it takes time and again the third time it is created easily....and then it takes time....


alternate times subfolder creation taking time......don't know what is the reason behind it.???

Comment: Again, there' no creation of a subfolder. The notion of folders or directories in azure blobs are a logical construct in place to help us visualize the data. "subfolder/dummy.png" is the file name. If there's an issue with creation of the file, there's two possibilities, either the storage client is attempting retries, or there's a delay in the upload. Without using fiddler or some other tool to more closely exam the underlying REST request/response trafic, its impossible to diagnose exactly what's going on. Its possible there is an issue in the storage account (I've seen that before as well).